# Aliasing Server Name in SSH Command

Tags: ubuntu, bash, alias, bashrc

This may be trivial, but I am not sure how do it safely and optimally.

I have a few servers (AWS EC2) into which I ssh from the bash. Those server names are long.

How can I alias them, so instead of typing the long thing, I can type something like

`ssh ubuntu@<alias-name>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

create a file `$HOME/.ssh/config` (or in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, if you want to install that alias system-wide), and put the following config inside:

```sh
Host myalias
    Hostname very-long-ugly-fqdn-hostname
    User ubuntu
    Port 22
```

after that, you are able to execute `ssh myalias` from any shell.

PS: of course, the setting `Port 22` is not necessary, since it is default. but this is supposed to show, that you can put any valid ssh option in a Host definition.